# Drawing Arrows on a Cubical

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose that an arrow is drawn on each edge of a cube, giving each edge a direction, in such a way that every vertex of the cube has at least one arrow coming out of it and at least one arrow going into it. Prove there exists a face of the cube such that the directions of the four boundary edges of that face go in a cycle.

So a cube has 6 faces, 8 vertices, and 12 edges, and there will be 12 arrows in total. each vertex has three edges with one in and two out or one out and two in. WLOG, we can assume one vertex for one in and two out and then we go to the adjacent vertices. Is there  an easier way to do this than just exhaust all possibilities by going through all vertices?

Answer (score 3):

The six faces of the cube have in total $24$ right angles. Such an angle is *good* if it can be traversed according to  the drawn arrows, and *bad* otherwise. It is easy to check that a face can have $0$, $2$, or $4$ bad angles. Now at each vertex of the cube we have two good angles and one bad angle, so that there are $8$ bad angles in total. It follows that there can be at most $4$ faces with $\geq2$ bad angles. This allows to conclude that here are $\geq2$ faces with a directed cycle going around them.

Comment: this is very helpful thansk but is there a way to use graph theory to explain this?

Comment: @jamesblack This is graph theory. The angles are just paths through vertices and the faces are the quadrangles. The rigid geometry of the cube just provides an intuitive way to talk about the graph.